# How to add page Title parameter for Android Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, ios, google-analytics

I am trying to configure Google Analytics for our Android App.

Works fine, all the activities show up as Pages.
What I am interested is to add Page Title so that I can see the Activity with the its title.

I am sure this is easy but I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tracker t = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(trackingId);
 t.setScreenName("Your Screen Name");

 t.setTitle("Your Page Title"); // This is the code to set Page Title.

 t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```